# How can I disable a hdd that has a mounted partition (windows 10)

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive

Once you go linux, windows looks weird...

I have 2 hdd, same model (used for linux mdadm), I want disable one of them (one has raids and linux partitions, other has raids and windows partitions, obviously I have no use for windows to access the first one).

But when I go to device manager, I am not allowed to disable any one of them. I suspect because the 1st hdd has one partition formatted as ntfs and is mounted. How can I unmount this useless partition and force device disable? As a last resort I guess I'll format the partition as ext4.

**Task manager and device manager:**

[image: Task manager and device manager]

**Windows partition:**

[image: windows partition]

I also have 3rd hdd, windows let me disable that one no problem (it had only one partition , a raid one).

Answer (score 2):

1) Open the Start menu and type "diskmgr.msc"

2) Right click on the partition to unmount and select "Change Driver Letter and Paths..."

3) Select the drive letter to remove and click the "Remove" button.

4) Locate the disk the partition resides on in the list at the bottom of the dialog and right click on the disk.

5) Select "Offline" from the list.

The disk and any NTFS partitions should now be completely unmounted.